# How to install node 4 version if node 5 already installed on windows

Tags: node.js, windows

I have node 5.1 installed but in order to build some projects I need node 4 installed in order to do that. When I donwloaded the node 4 installer it is says that I have newer version already installed:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would use Docker and run different Node versions inside separate containers, start and stop when needed.

Look at the official Node repo https://hub.docker.com/_/node/. There are all versions from 0.10 to 5.1.1 available.

Inside the project folder where you need a specific Node version, create a `Dockerfile` file and put this in:

```
FROM node:5.1.1
EXPOSE 8000 // The port on which your Node app runs
```

Then build the image from this config file by running:

```
$ docker build -t yourappname .
```

Finally run it:

```
$ docker run -it --rm --name yourappinstance yourappname
```

For another project you do the same except specifying a different Node version.

Comment: that is interesting idea to user docker which is I havent tryed yet.

Comment: More than that, you should try [docker-compose](http://docs.docker.com/compose/), which will help you run not only single images, but sets of them. For example, you need two instances of Redis and one instance of Mongo that run in one session for your project. With Docker Compose you can easily setup and run this scenario without garbaging the host system.

Comment: Will it all run on WIndows?

Comment: Docker Toolbox, which is the official all-in-one Docker app is available for Windows: (https://www.docker.com/docker-toolbox)[https://www.docker.com/docker-toolbox]. I run it on a Mac without any hassle but may be you will need to do some more work on Windows, have a look at their [start guide](http://docs.docker.com/windows/step_one/). Docker installs a virtual machine to run the containers so it doesn't run in the Windows environment, but in the virtual machine Linux instance it setups.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your Windows environment, use a Node version manager- for instance Nodist: https://github.com/marcelklehr/nodist
It will allow you to choose the version you require for your different projects.